# How do I make a floating div fixed width while the other two floating div in percentage?

Tags: html, css

Say I have 3 `div`s like this:

```css
#wrapper {width:100%; border:1px solid #ccc}
#wrapper div {box-sizing: border-box; float:left; border:1px solid #777}
#wrapper #first {width:30%}
#wrapper #second {width:70%}
#wrapper #third {width:30px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">A</div>
  <div id="second">B</div>
  <div id="third">C</div>
</div>
```

What I want:

1. The 3 divs all floating in a row in a flexible container;
2. The `width` of 3rd div is always a fixed value, like `30px`;
3. The first and second div has `width` in a percentage value, to use the rest room of the container.

For instance, if the container is 100px, the 3rd div is 30px and the first is `(100-30)*30% = 21px`, the second is `(100-30)*70% = 49px`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: consider reading *all* the answers and you will find *all* the possible ways with and without float

Answer (score 1):

You can use calc:

```css
#wrapper {width:100%; border:1px solid #ccc}
#wrapper div {box-sizing: border-box; float:left; border:1px solid #777}
#wrapper #first {width:calc(30% - 30px)}
#wrapper #second {width:calc(70% - 30px)}
#wrapper #third {width:30px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">A</div>
  <div id="second">B</div>
  <div id="third">C</div>
</div>
```

If you want, you can use a css variable to not have to write 30px three times.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `width` calculation for this. you can do something like this.

you can also do `max-width` to the selector class which you want keep varying the size dynamically and you can freeze the size of your last block i.e. `third` div.

```css
#wrapper {width:100%; border:1px solid #ccc}

#wrapper #first{
width:30%;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid red;
}
#wrapper #second{
width:60%;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid teal;
}
#wrapper #third{
width:30px;
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">A</div>
  <div id="second">B</div>
  <div id="third">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper {width:100%; border:1px solid #ccc}
#wrapper div {box-sizing: border-box; float:left; border:1px solid #777}
#wrapper #first {width:calc(30% - 15px)}
#wrapper #second {width:calc(70% - 15px)}
#wrapper #third {width:30px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">A</div>
  <div id="second">B</div>
  <div id="third">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When posting a possible solution, consider adding an explanation as to why it might help. This will make the question and answer more useful for future readers, who may want to learn from it as well.

Comment: Incidentally, I have removed "hope this helps" from your text, since there is a preference on Stack Overflow for technical writing. Everyone hopes their answer helps, so it is quite redundant. Please refrain from adding this (and any other conversational material) if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper {width:100%; border:1px solid #ccc; display: flex}
#wrapper div {box-sizing: border-box; float:left; border:1px solid #777}
#wrapper #first {flex-basis: 30%}
#wrapper #second {flex-basis: 70%}
#wrapper #third {flex-basis: 30px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="first">A</div>
  <div id="second">B</div>
  <div id="third">C</div>
</div>
```

Another way to achieve this using flexbox. Hope this helps.